# Can I use regular expressions in Django F() expressions?

Tags: python, sql, django, regex, postgresql

I have a model:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    long_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=256)
    important_A = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=256)
    important_B = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=256)
```

`MyModel.long_name` contains information, that I need to put in dedicated fields (`important_A` and `important_B`). An example of a string in `long_name` would be `S1_arctic_mosaic_tile_029r_016d_300_20221108T062432.png`

I basically need to match one part of the string in `long_name`, i.e. everything between the 4. and the 5. underscore ("`029r`") and put it into `important_A`, and everything between the 5. and the 6. ("`016d`") into `important_B`.

Since the database (PostgreSQL on Django 3.2.15) is quite big (~2.000.000 rows), looping (and using things like Python's `str.split()`) is not an option, as this would take too long.

I'm thus looking for a way to use regex in the migration to populate `important_A` and `important_B` from `long_field`. My current migration looks like this:

```py
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.db.models import F

def populate_fields(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model("myapp", "mymodel")
    MyModel.objects.all().update(important_A=
        F('long_name=r"S1_.*_(\d{2,3}(r|l)_\d{2,3}(u|d))_.*\.png"')
    )

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('icedata', '0036_something'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_fields),
    ]
```

When I try to run this migration, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'filename=r"S1_.*_(\d{2,3}(r|l)_\d{2,3}(u|d))_.*\.png"' into field. Choices are: long_name, id
```

When I instead use `F('long_name__regex=r"S1_.*_(\d{2,3}(r|l)_\d{2,3}(u|d))_.*\.png"')`, I instead get:

```py
Cannot resolve keyword 'regex=r"S1_.*_(\\d{2,3}(r|l)_\\d{2,3}(u|d))_.*\\.png"' into field. Join on 'long_name' not permitted.
```

How can I use regular expressions together with F()-expressions?
Or, if I can't, is there another way to use the database to extract part of a string and put it in another field?

Comment: I'm no SQL expert but I would expect that it can be done using SQL if you can find an expert!

Comment: Another way to go about it would be a queryset (and object manager) which annotates `important_A` and`important_B` onto the objects. They would then be read_only "fields" which always accurately reflect `long_name`. The code to calculate them expressed in Django queryset objects would be pretty horrendous. In raw SQL, perhaps less so (again, I'm no SQL expert).

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that updating 2M rows is "too slow", but you would definitely want to avoid creating two million objects at once, or doing 2M DB queries to update a single object. You might:

1. Edit the model to create important_A and important_B fields with default values which cannot ever be valid in production. (Blank or null, usually). Makemigrations and migrate.
2. Run code to update the database a sane number of objects at a time.

Something like:

```
DEFAULT = ''
BATCH_SIZE = 1000
while True:
    objects = list( MyModel.objects.filter( important_A=DEFAULT)[:BATCH_SIZE] )
    if len(objects) == 0:
         break   # all done
    for o in objects:

         # stuff to get new_A and new_B non-DEFAULT values
         o.important_A = new_A
         o.important_B = new_B
         assert new_A != DEFAULT, 'avoid infinite loop bug'
         n_updated = MyModel.objects.bulk_update( 
             objects, ['important_A','important_B']
         )
         assert n_updated == len(objects), 'WTF?' # return values should be checked
```

3. Implement methods on `MyModel` to make sure that the `important_A` and `important_B` fields can never get out of sync with `long_name` (if the relationship is permanent rather than as-of-now, that is). This could be the `save` method, or  properties with getters and setters to cross-reference the fields.

Comment: I didn't say that updating 2 million rows is too slow. I want to avoid two things: Making a query for each row and loading 2 million rows into memory. The latter might be a solvable problem (e.g. with batch sizes as you suggested). But for now I'm looking for a solution that consists of a single query, for example one that annotates the information in `long_name` into the new fields and then filters on them. The question is precisely: What would this annotate look like?

Comment: Which is exactly what my example does. One query to fetch BATCH_SIZE objects and one query to `batch_update` them. Slicing a queryset `[:BATCH_SIZE]` generates a new queryset, it doesn't evaluate the current one.

Comment: The annotate would require some raw SQL for a general case (if possible at all), because Django database functions don't include any indexing operations. They do provide concatenation and substring extraction with fixed offset and length.

Comment: @C4X You might be able to filter using `longname__regex=`, and then make `important_A` and `important_B` into python properties of the object. (With setters if necessary, to update long_name).

Comment: True, but what would this raw SQL look like?

Comment: @C4X As I said in my first comment, I'm no SQL expert. Re-post the question more explicitly as asking for raw SQL or PostgreSQL?